# mysql how to pass null parameter into stored procedure and test for it in sql statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

**NOTE: Solution for this issue has been attached at the bottom. :)**

5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) Using MySQL Console

Trying to Test this procedure out in mysql console. It actually involves numerous fields which maybe searched against. Some values maybe defined as NULL.

I was having troubles with the query with an ERROR #1064 which involved a NULL value at line 1.

Here is the query and it breaks when I added the `@P1 IS NULL` test. I saw this somewhere but cannot for the life of my find it again...

```
SET @p0='46,51,52,1317,1318,1319,1320,1322,1323'; 
SET @p1='500-000'; 
CALL `searchCount2`(@p0, @p1);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `searchCount2`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `searchCount2`(
IN _dealerIds varchar(100),
IN _dealerPhoneNumber varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
        SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT count(cID) 
        FROM tblclassifieds c
        JOIN tblphotos p 
        ON c.cmd5val=p.cClassCode 
        WHERE p.cpMain=1 
        AND c.cMarkedInappropriate=0 
        AND c.cBlacklisted=0 
        AND c.cEndDate>NOW() 
        AND (cType=29) OR (c.cType=27 OR c.cType=28) 
        AND c.cCompanyId IN (',_dealerIds,')
        AND (("',_dealerPhoneNumber,'" is null) or (c.cPhoneNum="',_dealerPhoneNumber,'"));');
    --  SELECT @query;
     PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
```

Retested the Above using quotes.

Here is the example I have which works before I added the `@P1 IS NULL`, but as I mentioned this query is far from complete. There are numerous parameters to search against.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `searchCount3`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `searchCount3`(
IN _dealerIds varchar(100),
IN _dealerPhoneNumber varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
        SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT count(cID) 
        FROM tblclassifieds c
        JOIN tblphotos p 
        ON c.cmd5val=p.cClassCode 
        WHERE p.cpMain=1 
        AND c.cMarkedInappropriate=0 
        AND c.cBlacklisted=0 
        AND c.cEndDate>NOW() 
        AND ((cType=29) OR (cType=27 OR cType=28))
        AND c.cCompanyId IN (',_dealerIds,')
        OR c.cPhoneNum=',_dealerPhoneNumber,';');
     -- SELECT @query;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
```

SO what is my error with this NULL error? Is there another way I should implement this? How can I test it in MySQL?

Is Set @p1=NULL; valid?

Please disregard the horrible naming convention.

Thanks for any help. I have been struggling with this for too long.

Here is a print off of the query before it executes, `SELECT @query`:

```
SELECT count(cID)
              FROM tblclassifieds c
              JOIN tblphotos p
              ON c.cmd5val=p.cClassCode
              WHERE p.cpMain=1
              AND c.cMarkedInappropriate=0
              AND c.cBlacklisted=0
              AND c.cEndDate>NOW()
              AND (cType=29)
              AND c.cCompanyId IN (46,51,52,1317,1318,1319,1320,1322,1323)
              OR (cType=27 OR cType=28)
              AND cCompanyId IN (46,51,52,1317,1318,1319,1320,1322,1323)
              AND ((579-7775 is null) or (c.cPhoneNum=579-7775));
```

I copy and paste this query into sql console and I get results. But Execute fails! Why is this so? Error #1064.

**SOLUTION:**

I removed the parameter test for _dealerPhoneNumber IS NULL and replaced it with _dealerPhoneNumber = "". This has fixed the issue.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `searchCount2`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `searchCount2`(
IN _dealerIds varchar(100),
IN _dealerPhoneNumber varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
        SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT count(cID) 
        FROM tblclassifieds c
        JOIN tblphotos p 
        ON c.cmd5val=p.cClassCode 
        WHERE p.cpMain=1 
        AND c.cMarkedInappropriate=0 
        AND c.cBlacklisted=0 
        AND c.cEndDate>NOW() 
        AND ((cType=29) AND cCompanyId IN (',_dealerIds,')) 
        OR ((cType=27 OR cType=28) AND cCompanyId IN (',_dealerIds,')) 
        AND (("',_dealerPhoneNumber,'" = "") or (c.cPhoneNum="',_dealerPhoneNumber,'"));');
    --  SELECT @query;
     PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
```

Comment: yes, `set @p1=null` is valid. you can trivially try that yourself in the mysql monitor. Exactly how/where are you doing this `@p1 is null` stuff?

Comment: @MarcB I'm trying to create a query which will search against many parameters that maybe defined. I'm thinking NULL mnay not be the best case. However its easier since I have numerous field types to test against.

Comment: @MarcB I'm testing on mysql console

Comment: well, `579-7775 is null` is wrong. that's an arithmetic subtraction, so you're basically saying `-7196 is null`. The phone number should have quotes around it, making it a string, not math.

Comment: @mgrenier But I thought you needed to common separate your values for CONCAT.

Comment: you are correct, that was my mistake, i misread your code and when I looked at it again I realized what you were doing.  That is why I deleted my comment.  Please disregard it.

Comment: do your code work when your parameters have values and only fails on nulls?

Comment: @mgrenier the output of the query above is before it is executed. I copy and paste that exact query and it runs perfectly.

Comment: @MarcB I added the quotes. That did not change a thing. I'm thinking the logic of testing if something IS NULL is what is breaking this.

Comment: right, but I mean the first code block where you are using parameters.  If you put actual values in for your parameters and not nulls do you get the results you expect?  I am trying to determine if the nulls are the problem or if it is something else.

Comment: @mgrenier If I remove the test case IS NULL the query executes as described above, but with it there I get an error #1064 after it reads `SELECT @query` Mind you the query output copy and pasted works.

Comment: you are mixing and/or statements (the ctype stuff) without any `()` to enforce the evaluation order. as written, you're doing `(x and y and z) or (p and q and r)`.

Comment: @mgrenier I'm starting to think this is more than just passing in NULL values. But I have nothing to test that since my current case is not working.

Comment: @MarcB Yes you are right. This is a copy and paste of form a project where everything is jumbled together. I'm trying to undo the mess. I'll clean that up now. Thank you.

Comment: seems like you have some sort of parameter issue, maybe try getting it working using variables hardcoded in the stored procedure first to make sure that part is working, then try making the variables into parameters.  What I mean by that is create your _dealerIDs and _dealerPhoneNumbers in the stored procedure and set the values to test values you know to be working.  Make sure that works, once it does then move to parameters.  Baby steps, that should help you determine where the issue lies.

Comment: I did take baby steps... I think I figured it out. The test against IS NULL is not working, so I swapped it for empty string "" and I got results. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to define the parameters as null on the creation.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `searchCount3`(
IN _dealerIds varchar(100) = NULL,
IN _dealerPhoneNumber varchar(10) = NULL
)
```

Comment: I don't believe MySQL allows default values.

Comment: Oh you're right. The ERROR #1064 is an syntax error. you've try an print after the EXECUTE stmt; to see the query?

Comment: I added an output of the statement in problem above.

Comment: what kind of data is c.cPhoneNum?

Comment: VARCHAR(100) and NULL is allowed, if I remove the test IS NULL for the field I am able to get results.

Comment: try to use simple qoutes on that value.

Comment: I added " " around the parameter `"',_dealerPhoneNumber,'"` It didn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was passing NULL to a MySQL stored procedure and getting this error message that I thought was obscure:

`ERROR #1064 which involved a 'NULL' value at line 1.`

I thought maybe passing NULL to stored procedures was not allowed, but it is allowed.

My issue was in the stored procedure, specifically:

- I was dynamically generating an insert statement via a call to CONCAT, AND
- i was not guarding against the presence of NULL, so i ended up with a quoted 'NULL' in my insert statement

By adding a condition in my string concatenation to account for NULL i was able to fix my issue

```
BEFORE

...
"more_info_link = '", more_info_link, "', ",
...

AFTER

IF(more_info_link IS NULL,
  "more_info_link = NULL, ",
  CONCAT("more_info_link = '", more_info_link, "', ")
),
```