# How Get result From Null parameter value in dynamic MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table name **`table_abc`**  it contain coloumns **`name varchar(255) NOT NULL,store_id INT(11) NOT NULL,brand varchar(255) NOT NULL,status INT(11) NOT NULL`** .

table -

```
 name   | store_id  | brand |       status
    dress      1         only           1
    dress      2        vero moda       1
    dress      2         ZARA           1
    dress      2        vero moda       1
    dress      3         only           1
    dress      3        vero moda       1
    dress      1         only           1
    dress      2        ZARA            1
```

NOw i want dynamic results if pass NULL or empty `''` values in parameters then it can give whole rows of that particuler parameter as results .  For example :

```
 delimiter //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_test//
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(
    list_of_name VARCHAR(255), 
    list_of_ids VARCHAR(100), 
    list_of_brand VARCHAR(100) )
    BEGIN
         SET @query := CONCAT("SELECT name,store_id,brand,status FROM `table_abc`  
    WHERE name in (" , list_of_name ,") AND status='1' 
    AND store_id in (" , list_of_ids OR list_of_ids IS NULL, ")
     AND brand in (" , list_of_brand , ") 
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,16");
         PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
         EXECUTE stmt;
         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
         END//
         delimiter ;
```

we trying to get result with null value parameter.  but store_id can't working in this procedure. or null also not working . **Please help**

- `mysql> call sp_test("'dress'",'1,2,3',"'only','vero moda','ZARA'");`
- `mysql> call sp_test("'dress'",null,"'only','vero moda','ZARA'");`
- `mysql> call sp_test("'dress'",'null',"'only','vero moda','ZARA'");`

Comment: What is type of store_id- INT, CHAR or VARCHAR ?

Comment: @KeyurPanchal  name varchar(255),store_id INT(11),brand varchar(255),status INT(11) . sir  type is already define in descrition

Answer (score 1):

try something like this (I have not tested the script, so you may need to adjust it a little)

```
 delimiter //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_test//
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(
    list_of_name VARCHAR(255), 
    list_of_ids VARCHAR(100), 
    list_of_brand VARCHAR(100) )
    BEGIN
         SET @query := CONCAT("SELECT name,store_id,brand,status FROM `table_abc`  
    WHERE name in (" , list_of_name ,") AND status='1' 
     + CASE WHEN ISNULL(list_of_ids,'') <> '' THEN "AND store_id in (" + list_of_ids + ") 
     AND brand in (" , list_of_brand , ") 
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,16");
         PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
         EXECUTE stmt;
         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
         END//
         delimiter ;
```

Comment: thanxs and sir how to call procedure please tell me, means how to define null or empty in parameters

Comment: you can send null directly as is to an SP .. Exec MySP 'abc',null,'efg' or you can see more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194414/mysql-how-to-pass-null-parameter-into-stored-procedure-and-test-for-it-in-sql-st

Comment: unknown coloumn or data type